# return a local variable in c++ cause destructor freeze

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

this is sample code

class a

```
class a {
public:
    int *i;
    a() {
        i = new int;
    }
    ~a(){
        delete i;
    }
};
```

method returnA()

```
a returnA() {
    a A;
    A.i = new int;
    return A;
}
```

and then I called returnA in main()

```
int main() {
    returnA();
}
```

this throws a exception when the code run to the 'delete i' inside ~a(),  when I change returnA() to allacote A on heap, the problem goes away, what's the difference for i, didn't it allocated on heap all the time, cause I use new in constructor, please show me some light

Comment: You need a proper copy constructor (and assignment operator) that handles the dynamic memory allocation.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Returning local variable. Might be overwritten in the stack by some other function/method call.